# Matlab reading endian-incorrect binary data input / interpreting as uint32

Tags: matlab, serial-port, endianness

While writing this post, I attempted b = fread(s, 1, 'uint32')

This would work great, but my poor data is sent LSB first! (no I can not change this)

Before, I was using b = fread(s, 4)' which gives me a vector similar to [47 54 234 0].
Here is my input stream:

```
0A
0D 39 EA 00 04 39 EA 00
4B 39 EA 00 D0 38 EA 00
0A
etc...
```

I can successfully delimit by 0x0A by

```
while ~isequal(fread(s, 1), 10) end
```

Basically I need to get the array of uint32s represented by [00EA390D 00EA3904 00EA394B 00EA38D0]
The documentation for swapbytes doesn't help me much and the uint32 operator operates on individual elements!!

Comment: It seems like typecast(uint8(b), 'uint32') will work. Matlab must have needed to have been told what datatype the elements of b were. I am on what I assume is a little endian system (W7 x64)

Comment: I never worked with serial I/O, but there seem to be a `ByteOrder` property for the `serial` object: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-started-with-serial-i-o.html#f61191

Answer (score 1):

The matlab [fread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) function directly supports little endian machine format.  Just set the 5th argument of the fread function to the string "L".

```
b = fread(s, 4, 'uint32',0,'l');
```